# Find partition letters on physical drives using wmic

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-pe, wmic

I am looking for a way to list drives and the partitions on them. Specifically I am looking to prompt a user for a drive to format and I want to show them the exists partitions so they can confirm their choice.

I have found the wmic commands to list disk drives, logical disks, partitions, and volumes but I can not find a way associate the volumes to physical drives.

I also found a powershell script that does what I want. The script uses gwmi and I don't know how to convert the commands into wmic.
http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/using-wmi-to-link-a-disk-volume-to-a-physical-disk-with-powershell/

Is there a way to get a list of volumes on a physical disk using wmic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `wmic` command is a bit different than either the VB or  PowerShell syntax.

The relevant syntax for `wmic` is:

```
wmic <command> where <conditional> Assoc /assocclass:<class>
```

Specifically to solve the task above:

```
wmic DiskDrive where "DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE<disk_index>'" Assoc /assocclass:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
```

Will return the partitions on the drive with the given index.

```
wmic partition where (DeviceID="<partition_id>") assoc /assocclass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
```

Will return the volumes on the partition with the given id.